# netsuite join on suitetalk searches

Tags: join, netsuite

If I read correctly, in SuiteScript you can do a search that brings back a joint of two record types if they are parent child types of records even if they are custom recordTypes
(such as for example Customer record with a custom child RepairHistory record tied to it.  If I understand correctly, you can do a search that will return the combination of the Customer record fields joined with the repairHistroy entries that are tied to that customer (kind of like a normal SQL join).

My question is, can this be done in SuiteTalk - and if so can it be any records including custom ones - and if so, how would it look.  We are using C# but any examples are acceptable.

John

Answer (score 2):

Create a saved search in Netsuite. Call the saved search via SuiteTalk and add additional criteria to filter the search results approriately.

Comment: I have made a saved search which I was going to call but the issue is that when I call it I get errors.  I put each of the following attempts which all failed in c#..

Comment: I made a search but in referring to it in code I get errors that either "A saves search with internal ID 742 doesnt exist.  Or Saves search with script id 742 doesnt exist or A saved search with internal ID customsearchspike doesnt exist.  I confirmed that I have a saved search with internal ID of 742 and it is named 'customsearchspike'.   example code transSearchAdv = new TransactionSearchAdvanced { savedSearchId = "742" }; or new TransactionSearchAdvanced { savedSearchId = "customsearchspike" }; or transSearchAdv3 = new TransactionSearchAdvanced { savedSearchScriptId = "customsearchspike"

Answer (score 1):

here are a few code samples using PHP toolkit

https://dreamxtream.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/netsuite-php-toolkit-tips-and-code-samples/

Last example is for **join search**.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a saved search may work
However, it will be highly dependent on what sort of record type is returned by the search as the result. If you get problems with "does not exist" errors make sure your code is using the correct object types to capture the result.

Additionally, some of your results may not be useful info (internalIDs come back for many things). Those might be able to be scoped to the right object type in your saved search using the proper "Table...Fields" in your result columns. But there are no guarantees you will be able to access those joined table fields.

If that happens you would either have to grab that whole table needed to join the internalID to get the value you want or, much more slowly, change your process to look up each ID field in each row during processing of your saved search results.

Either way really is terrible. This is a known problem, I have logged it with NetSuite and received an Enhancement item for it. However it seems unlikely this will get fixed any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done.  In suitetalk, the joins are done using the XXXSearch object (as opposed to the xxxSearchBasic object).

```
CustomerSearch.basic = new CustomerSearchBasic();
CustomerSearch.customSearchJoin = new CustomSearchJoin[] { new CustomSearchJoin() };
CustomerSearch.customSearchJoin[0].customizationRef = new CustomizationRef() { scriptId = "field_id_of_parent_record_for_join" };
CustomerSearch.customSearchJoin[0].recordSearchBasic = new CustomRecordSearchBasic();
```

The "customizationRef' is the field referencing the joined record from the parent record, which corresponds to the 'CustomRecord (field name)...' when you do a join using the saved search UI.